# Can't play audio on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-external-storage, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I recently created a simple music player that reads wav audio files from external storage. I used to test it on android 4.4 and everything worked fine. Now testing it on Lollipop it doesn't work anymore. It somehow doesn't set the data source right anymore and so exception e is thrown... Why is that?

Here is my code:

```
try {
                        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                                "/a/b/", mMessages.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMusiKPath())));
                        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                        mPlayer.prepare();
}catch (Exception e)
```

Comment: Please provide the error message, what error exactly are you getting? And also the code before the `try` may be helpful.

Comment: there is no err msg there is just an exception thrown

Answer (score 0):

I think u didn't ask permission for reading  Storage when you want use storage.
android lolipop and above need asking permission when want use it